# how can i combine columns in one columns in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have list of universities. Universities has columns of keywords. I need to make 2 mode matrix (universities X keyword) with using pivot table. so i need to combine separeted keyword columns under one column with their universities. I tried adding universities columns between keywords columns and than cut-paste one by one each university-keyword column under A and B column. But it is not easy to do when keywords gets more. This image is an example of what i need. How can i achive that transformation 1 to 2. Thanks for answers.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like a quick `Index/Match` may work, no?  Also, can you clarify, you're just trying to create the "2" table, correct?

Comment: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/05/07/vba-macro-normalize-data/

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes i want to create table 2 from table 1. But then i create table 3 with table 2. So i need table 2 actually.

Comment: @Tim Williams it looks what i need. I am going to try it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a macro able to split cell value into rows.
Should able to help you go thru step 1 to step 2.

What [Split To Row Macro](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Nwt2ZUDPSzQ2NQdTVfdWNpb2s) can do:
[image]

Firstly, create a concatenate value for all columns into 1 as below
[image]

Then using column Id and the concatenate column only, Run Split To Row macro will able convert data into long list.

[image][image]